# Prepare JSON data for bootstrap treeview in C#(MVC4)

Tags: c#, json, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

Hi my **requirement** is show user details in ***boot strap treeview***

here i am getting user data through linq query from  SQL database

this is sample JSON data in this way how to prepare data in C#

**NOTE:** bootstrap treeview will work only with those key names should be same as mentioned in data **text** and **nodes** but in my c# class i have different field names **as shown in below screen shot**   [image: I need to show like this]  [image]

**Sample JSON Data** **-->  how to prepare data like this in C#**

```
var treeData = [{
            text: "UserName 1", nodes: [ {
                text: "First Name1"
            },
       {
           text: "Last Name1"
       },
       {
           text: "User Orders 1",
           nodes: [
             {
                 text: "Order 1"
             },
             {
                 text: "Order 2"
             }
           ]
       },
       {
           text: "User Locations 1",
           nodes: [
             {
                 text: "Location 1"
             },
             {
                 text: "Location 2"
             }
           ]
       }

            ]
        },
       {
           text: "UserName 2", nodes: [{
               text: "First Name 2"
           },
      {
          text: "Last Name 2"
      },
      {
          text: "User Orders 2",
          nodes: [
            {
                text: "Order 1"
            },
            {
                text: "Order 2"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
          text: "User Locations 2",
          nodes: [
            {
                text: "Location 1"
            },
            {
                text: "Location 2"
            }
          ]
      }

           ]
       }
        ];
```

Comment: Post your C# class which needs to be converted to this JSON format

Answer (score 2):

First, create a class to use as a treeview node:

```
[Serializable]
public class TreeviewNodeEntity
{
    public string text { get; set; }

    public string[] tags { get; set; }

    public TreeviewNodeEntity[] nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Second, create an action in a controller where the data set of nodes for the treeview is created. Return this as Json data. Notice that the root object to return (returnObject) is an array of node objects. In the tags property (of type string array) you can store an id value or other data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTreeData(int mainItem)
{
    TreeviewNodeEntity[] returnObject = new TreeviewNodeEntity[2];

    TreeviewNodeEntity rootNode1 = new TreeviewNodeEntity();
    rootNode1.text = "Username 1";
    rootNode1.tags = new string[1];
    rootNode1.tags[0] = "1";
    returnObject[0] = rootNode1;

    rootNode1.nodes = new TreeviewNodeEntity[2];

    TreeviewNodeEntity childNode = new TreeviewNodeEntity();
    childNode.text = "First name1";
    childNode.tags = new string[1];
    childNode.tags[0] = "11";
    rootNode1.nodes[0] = childNode;

    childNode = new TreeviewNodeEntity();
    childNode.text = "Last name1";
    childNode.tags = new string[1];
    childNode.tags[0] = "12";
    rootNode1.nodes[1] = childNode;

    TreeviewNodeEntity rootNode2 = new TreeviewNodeEntity();
    rootNode2.text = "Username 2";
    rootNode2.tags = new string[1];
    rootNode2.tags[0] = "2";
    returnObject[1] = rootNode2;

    return Json(returnObject);
}
```

Finally, open the view where the treeview must be shown and add this Javascript code. It uses Jquery, so make sure to install this in your project.

```
function BuildTree() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/NameOfController/GetTreeData",
        async: false,
        data: "{'mainItem':'2'}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            if (data) {
                $('#tree').treeview({
                    data: data,
                    enableLinks: true,
                    showBorder: false,
                    onNodeSelected: function (event, data) {
                        if (data.tags instanceof Array) {
                            DoStuffWhenClickingOnNode(data.tags[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forget the tree element in Html:

```
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: what if the data is dynamic or data coming from List<object>

Comment: Well, I guess you have to build some code which generates the returnObject with the node objects from your list.

Answer (score 0):

Add names above declarations in classes

```
    [DataContract(Name = "MyName")]
    internal class Person
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "xName")]
        internal string name;

        [DataMember(Name = "Age in Years")]
        internal int age;
    }
```